# Solve for $x$ and represent the solutions on the trig circle?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin(4x)\cos(x)+2\sin(x)\cos^2(2x) = 1- 2\sin^2(x)$$

I'm confused.

Comment: Tried anything at all?

Comment: I know that I should use the fundamenal equation, but I cant seem to recognise it here

Answer (score 2):

Since $1-2\sin^2(x)=\cos (2x)$ and $\sin (2\alpha)=2\sin (\alpha)\cos (\alpha)$ we have
$$2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)\cos(x)+2\sin(x)\cos^2(2x)=\cos(2x)$$
$$\cos (2x)[2\sin(2x)\cos(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(2x)-1]=0$$
Then either $\cos (2x)=0$ or  $2\sin(2x)\cos(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(2x)-1=0$.

Comment: thankks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
\cos(2x) = \cos(x + x) = \ldots \\
\sin(4x) = \sin(2x + 2x) = \ldots
$$

Answer (score 0):

continue @Mario G'answer with $2\sin(2x)\cos(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(2x)-1=0 \Rightarrow‎ 2sin3x-1=0\Rightarrow‎ sin3x=\frac{1}{2}$.....

$\sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b+\sin b \cos a$

Comment: you are welcome dear